# Getting data from a dataset in Django

Tags: python, django, dataframe, dataset

I have a dataset that I am trying to read data from and display on my site I am using the Pandas package to read the data into a DataFrame.

I want to display a subset of the data on my Django website, however I don't know what is the correct way of achiving this, should I import the dataset into my PostgreSQL database and read from there?

Comment: if your dataset is big and panda takes time reading the data, it's better to use a database but you have to enter you data into database first

Comment: @ParitoshYadav what if the dataset is not that big? How would I go about using the DataFrame in my webpage?

Comment: depend on what type of dataset you have, can you show  your dataset(not whole just to get the idea)

Comment: you can store your dataset in list or dict and simply render them in your HTML page using Django in a html table or however you like

Comment: @ParitoshYadav You can check this out https://saa-d.github.io/top-n-recommender/ it is my code, the final dataframe is the one I am trying to display on the website

Answer (score 0):

(if you dont want to store data in database)

you can use the Bootstrap table to display data in HTML template

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/content/tables/

store each column in a list then store all the list in dict and render them

```
context={
'data':list1,
'data2':list2,
}

return render(request,'table.html',context)
```

you use Django built-in template for loop to iterate through and display all the data

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/